# Parse text inside <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to make a simple web application that allows me to upload a text file and display its contents in a  tag. Also, when I press the "Parse" button, I need the text content to only keep all lines starting with "ACK" while maintaining its structure.

Here is my code:

```js
// Javascript App.js
document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(){      
        document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = this.result;      
    }
    
    fr.readAsText(file);
},false)



//error zone
document.getElementById("parse").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent.startsWith("ACK") = this.result;
},false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Parser</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="openFile"/>
    <button id="parse">Parse</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- preformatted text -->  
    <pre id="fileContents"></pre>
    <!--/preformatted text -->  

    <!-- app.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

[example off the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9qVs.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of the input text file contents, and the expected output?

Comment: Sure @CertainPerformance. Imagine that you have a text file with these lines:

ACK somthing 
something
ACK something
ACK somthing 
something
ACK something
something
...

I just need  the ones that start with "ACK"

Comment: Can you edit it into your question? (Not into the comment box, it'll be unreadable)

Comment: Sure sorry....I never used stackoverflow so i will try to do it

Comment: Can you edit the input and expected output into your question, so we have a runnable example to debug? (as text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only changes were to the event listener of the `parse` button. I parsed the text of `fileContents` so when clicking `parse` the only lines left are the ones that begins with `ACK`.

```js
// Javascript App.js
document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(){      
        document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = this.result;      
    }
    
    fr.readAsText(file);
},false)



document.getElementById("parse").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let lines = document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent.split('\n');
    lines = lines.filter((line)=>line.indexOf('ACK')===0);
    let newPre = '';
    lines.map((line)=>{newPre+=line + '\n';});
    document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = newPre;
},false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Parser</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="openFile"/>
    <button id="parse">Parse</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- preformatted text -->  
    <pre id="fileContents"></pre>
    <!--/preformatted text -->  

    <!-- app.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i wanted to get lines with ACK and another combo off letters like NMG or JKO how could i do that?

Comment: Look at the line where I uses filter. Filter is a high order function that returns new array with all items that satisfying the condition. Right now the condition is whether the first sub string is ACK. Just change it to what you want

Comment: I was not saying change the string "ACK", but rather add another string like this:
lines = lines.filter ((line) => line.indexOf ('ACK') === 0 || line.indexOf ('KMH') === 0);
and it is not working

Comment: Your example will work only if the line starts with ACK or KMH (because you compare the index to 0)